# NFS-Ganesha: Function not implemented

Tags: c, linux, centos, nfs

I am trying to setup NFS Ganesha on CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core).
I installed the NFS-Ganesha package and started the nfs server through systemctl.

NFS-Ganesha Config

```
$ cat /etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf
EXPORT
{
    Export_Id = 77;
    Path = /home/test;
    Protocols = 3,4;
    Pseudo = /home/test;
    Access_Type = RW;
    FSAL {
        Name = VFS;
    }
    CLIENT {
        Clients = *;
    }
}
```

NFS-Ganesha Status

```
$ sudo systemctl status nfs-ganesha
● nfs-ganesha.service - NFS-Ganesha file server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-ganesha.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-02 06:26:18 UTC; 22min ago
     Docs: http://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/wiki
  Process: 108107 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c prlimit --pid $MAINPID --nofile=$NOFILE:$NOFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 108088 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ${NUMACTL} ${NUMAOPTS} /usr/bin/ganesha.nfsd ${OPTIONS} ${EPOCH} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 108106 (ganesha.nfsd)
    Tasks: 32
   Memory: 4.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-ganesha.service
           └─108106 /usr/bin/ganesha.nfsd -L /var/log/ganesha.log -f /etc/ganesha/ganesha.conf -N N...
```

systemd[1]: Starting NFS-Ganesha file server...
systemd[1]: Started NFS-Ganesha file server.

Couldn't see the service using `showmount -e` & could not mount it.

```
 $ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o proto=tcp,vers=3,nolock 127.0.0.1:/home/test /home/data/test
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue May  2 06:58:05 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,vers=3,nolock,addr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 127.0.0.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 46459
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/home/test
```

Thus, was trying to export the same.

```
$ sudo exportfs -a
exportfs: 127.0.0.1:/home/test: Function not implemented
```

Could someone please help with what might be the issue here?